# readfile function returning file content in non ASCII characters

Tags: php, html

When I execute the following code, image is not displayed in the browser , rather non ASCII symbols and characters are displayed instead.Few lines are as follows:

> ����JFIF��6Photoshop
>   3.08BIMgqarIDeY1blFS2krGbsOU��ICC_PROFILElcmsmntrRGB XYZ �)9acspAPPL���-lcms
>   desc�^cprt\wtpthbkpt|rXYZ�gXYZ�bXYZ�rTRC�@gTRC�@bTRC�@descc2textFBXYZ
>   ���-XYZ 3�XYZ o�8��XYZ b����XYZ
>   $����curv��c�k�?Q4!�)�2;�FQw]�kpz���|�i�}���0����C      !*$(
>   %2%(,-/0/#484.7*./.��C

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['logSyscuruser'])) {
// logged in
$id = $_SESSION['logSyscuruser'];


$imgLocation = '/Applications/XAMPP/im/';

include "include/specificproductDB.php";
$data = new specificPro();

  $out = $data->select($query, $id, $pId);
  $count = count($out);


}

else
{
  //not logged in
header("Location: loginSystem/login.php", true, 302);
die();
}



?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>
<div id="section">
<div id="header">
 <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
  <p>
<?php
if($count==0)
{
    echo "Nothing added till now.";
}

else
{

for ($x = $count-1; $x >= 0; $x--)
  {

   if(strlen($out[$x][0]) == 68)
   {
    //file is detected
    $imgPath = $imgLocation . $out[$x][0];

    // Make sure the file exists
    if(!file_exists($imgPath) || !is_file($imgPath))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        die('The file does not exist');
    }

    $imgData = substr($out[$x][0],65,3);

    // Set the appropriate content-type
    // and provide the content-length.
    header('Content-type: ' . $imgData);
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($imgPath));

    // Print the image data
    readfile($imgPath);
    }

   else
   {

    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('Fatal Error: Absurd entry in the database media table');
   }

   echo "<br><br>";

   }

  }

  ?>
  </p>

    <input type="button" value="Add Media" onclick="window.location = 'addMedia.php';">    

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what exactly is the value of `$imgData = substr($out[$x][0],65,3);` that you're sending in headers as the content type? That's what tells the browser whether the file is an image or not

Comment: And those "non ASCII" characters are the image, correctly sent by readfile as a stream of binary characters

Comment: it contains extension or mime type of the image file.

Comment: However, you're also sending a stream of html markup to the browser, in addition to the image..... browsers are stupid little bits of software, easily confused if you don't send the right information to them

Comment: Simply sending a file extension as a content type means nothing, you need to send the correct mime type value for the type of data/image/file that you're sending

Comment: i m sending the correct mime type, i just checked.

Comment: So the content type value isn't the extension, but you're still sending a mix of html markup and a raw binary image in the same request..... you can only send one or the other, but not both